# How to search questions that are asked today?

Tags: support, search

I wanted to search the questions tagged with jquery but should result only of today.

So, is there any way to search the questions by using the date?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
[jquery] created:2014-04-18 is:question
```

[Result](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery%5D+created%3A2014-04-18+is%3Aq)

Comment: Oh! thanks, created: method is not there even in clicking advance search tips. thanks a lot.

Comment: You can find it here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching

Comment: even better. thank you for providing the link.

Comment: how can I search the questions tagged with jquery only??

Comment: You can exclude tags from your search like this: `-[java]`

Comment: It means I've to exclude a lot of tags??

Comment: Normally you would not want the combination of specific tags. Does not make much sense to only want to see [jquery] not absolutely no other tags. I don't know a method to search like this in live data.